# setting proxy in selenium in python for IE browser

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, iedriverserver

My question is about setting proxy in selenium coding in python (3.6) for IE browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "94.56.171.137"
PORT = 8080

base_url = "https://google.com"

desired_capability = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER
desired_capability['proxy'] = {
    "proxyType": "manual",
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "httpProxyPort": PORT,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxyPort": PORT,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxyPort": PORT,
    "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
}

driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='C:\\tmp\\IEDriverServer',capabilities=desired_capability)
driver.get(base_url)
```

I am getting the below Error message -

```
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="http://127.0.0.1:54684/session">http://127.0.0.1:54684/session</a></p>
```

I took the reference from the below -

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949274/setting-proxy-in-selenium-in-python-for-firefox-geckodriver?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa
```

And its working fine in FireFox browser but I am not able to run in IE browser.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were pretty close. As you are on *Windows OS* you need to add the extension of the *WebDriver Binary* (i.e. **`.exe`**). Additionally, put the absolute path of the *IEDriverServer* within single quotes (i.e. **`''`**) along with *File separator* as *single front slash* (i.e. **`\`**) preceeded by the raw (i.e. **`r`**) switch as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'C:\tmp\IEDriverServer.exe', capabilities=desired_capability)
```